# Exclude node_modules from "problems"

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, tsconfig

I'm running this task:

```
{
        "taskName": "tsc watch",
        "command": "tsc -w",
        "type": "shell",
        "problemMatcher": "$tsc-watch"
}
```

with this tsconfig:

```
{
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "files": [
        "src/index.ts"
    ],
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "dist/"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

the file `index.ts` only has one line in it:

```
console.log('Is it working?');
```

And the "problems" tab is filled with HTML related warnings from random npm modules. Why? And how do i stop it?

**Edit1:** 
I managed to find a hack that works, by excluding the node_modules folder from the explorer:

```
/* settings.json */
{
    "files.exclude": {
        "**/node_modules": true
    }
}
```

However this is a hack, and i still want a proper answer..

Answer (score 144, accepted):

I stumbled upon this issue as well.
The only solution I found was add the `skipLibCheck` option and set it to true in the `compilerOptions` of my tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "skipLibCheck": true
    }
}
```

According to [the doc](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html), it will skip type checking of all declaration files (*.d.ts), which were the ones throwing the warnings in my case.

Comment: mmm not working for me :(

Answer (score 4):

All you should need is a `tsconfig.json` with:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "skipLibCheck": true,
    }
}
```

Comment: This adds absolutely nothing to the accepted answer

Comment: Hmmm, I just realized that your answer was the better one before the last edit of the accepted answer. Sorry.

Comment: and again, this doesn't work for me either.

Answer (score -2):

I have found another "cheat" for making that problem disappear after I tried everything and nothing worked.
I added at the end of the file:

```js
export {}
```

This somehow worked. I am not happy with that solution but that's the only thing that worked for me.