# Typescript upgrade and chrome types conflict

Tags: typescript, google-chrome-extension, typescript-typings

I have just upgraded from Typescript 4.2.4 to Typescript 4.8.4 and am now getting errors because the types in node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts conflict with the types node_modules/@types/filesystem/index.d.ts which is used by the "chrome" type in the types entry of the tsconfig file.

The errors are:

```
node_modules/@types/filesystem/index.d.ts:107:5 - error TS2687: All declarations of 'name' must have identical modifiers.

107     name: string;
        ~~~~

node_modules/@types/filesystem/index.d.ts:113:5 - error TS2687: All declarations of 'root' must have identical modifiers.

113     root: DirectoryEntry;
        ~~~~

node_modules/@types/filesystem/index.d.ts:113:5 - error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'root' must be of type 'FileSystemDirectoryEntry', but here has type 'DirectoryEntry'.

113     root: DirectoryEntry;
        ~~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:5248:14
    5248     readonly root: FileSystemDirectoryEntry;
                      ~~~~
    'root' was also declared here.

node_modules/@types/filesystem/index.d.ts:369:11 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'DOMError'.

369     (err: DOMError): void;
              ~~~~~~~~

node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:5247:14 - error TS2687: All declarations of 'name' must have identical modifiers.

5247     readonly name: string;
                  ~~~~

node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:5248:14 - error TS2687: All declarations of 'root' must have identical modifiers.
```

Apart from the missing "DomError" the errors are occurring because FileSystem is declared differently in the 2 declaration files.

filesystem.index.d.ts has an interface called FileSystem

```
interface FileSystem {
    /**
     * This is the name of the file system. The specifics of naming filesystems is unspecified, but a name must be unique across the list of exposed file systems.
     * @readonly
     */
    name: string;

    /**
     * The root directory of the file system.
     * @readonly
     */
    root: DirectoryEntry;
}
```

lib/lib.dom.d.ts also has an interface called FileSystem that looks like this:

```
interface FileSystem {
    readonly name: string;
    readonly root: FileSystemDirectoryEntry;
}
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: I'm not quite sure but if I remember correctly but you should exclude /node_modules/ from compilation via tsconfig.json

Comment: Try switching to the **official** [chrome-types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chrome-types) package.

Comment: Enable `skipLibCheck` in your TSConfig

Answer (score 1):

The `FileSystem` types are embedded in `dom.d.ts` [since 4.4](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-DOM-lib-generator/issues/1029).

You don't need `@types/filesystem` anymore.

Comment: it's a dependency of chrome types that is automatically installed by npm. I fixed the problems by specifying the latest filesystem types.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to the latest @types/filesystem fixed this.

Answer (score -1):

Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45744513/12800045

it says that you can skip typechecking libraries in your compiler options